# Случаи неправильного построения причастного оборота

Tags: морфология, причастный-оборот

Делая задания по русскому я столкнулся со следующим предложением:

> «Все активнее развертывается революционная пропаганда и шире становится круг людей, поднимающихся на борьбу»

Подскажите, где здесь ошибка в построении причастного оборота, и есть ли она вообще?

Comment: С причастным оборотом проблем нет, в отличие от деепричастного.

Comment: @М_Г, а в чем собственно ошибка, не подскажете?

Comment: Отсутствие запятой в предложении с деепричастным оборотом: "Делая задания по русскому,(!) я столкнулся со следующим предложением."